# Instant message web service use socket.io

Tags: web-services, socket.io, instant-messaging

I am developing an instant messaging web service, using Socket.IO. You can imagine it, workig like faceboọk chat. 
I need to make a report to my teacher and I don't know what type of web service is this? I don't think that it is a RESTFul web services. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket.IO is a java script based web api. It follows client server architecture but it's not a web service.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket.IO

http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

Socket.IO uses the Web Sockets protocol, with a fallback to other techniques when a client uses an ancient browser.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Comment: I chose xhr-polling instead of websocket